# Facing memory leak because of third party analytics thread

Tags: leakcanary

> (standard input):10240:D/LeakCanary( 4167): 
>   * GC ROOT thread
>   com.apsalar.sdk.ApsalarThread. (named 'ApsalarHTTPThread')
>   (standard input):10241:D/LeakCanary( 4167): 
>   * leaks
>   .MainActivity instance (standard
>   input):10243:D/LeakCanary( 4167): 
>   * Device: samsung samsung GT-S7562
>   kylexx (standard input):10244:D/LeakCanary( 4167): 
>   * Android Version:
>   4.0.4 API: 15 LeakCanary: 1.3.1 (standard input):10245:D/LeakCanary( 4167): 
>   * Durations: watch=5023ms, gc=829ms, heap dump=9032ms,
>   analysis=47771ms

Does above log says that Apsalar thread is the reason for memory leaks ?

Answer (score 0):

`ApsalarHTTPThread` thread has a reference to `MainActivity` while  `ApsalarHTTPThread` thread is running, even if you have finished your `MainActivity`.

You can try `getApplicationContext()` instead of `MainActivity.this`.